# use Angular routing in AngularJS/Angular hybrid app reload all page

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am trying to make Angular routing in my AngularJS/Angular hybrid application.
I created app-routing.module.ts file :

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule, ExtraOptions } from '@angular/router';
import {SignInComponent} from "./modules/login/components/sign-in/sign-in.component";
import {ActivationComponent} from "./modules/login/components/activation/activation.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'sign-in',
    component: SignInComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'activation',
    component: ActivationComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/activation'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/activation'
  }
];

export const routingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

in app.module.ts I added routingModule to "imports" array and in app.component.html I added :

```
<button (click)="goto('sign-in')">go to home</button>
<button (click)="goto('activation')">go to product</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When insight by index.html i am using just Angular it works perfectly

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

But when I am adding my AngularJS code just adding

```
this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

my current Angular routing instead reload content of "router-outlet" tag, reloads completely the page. If I remove

```
this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

it works fine.
Does anybody had some similar issues and maybe someone can propose some scenario how to make Angular routing work appropriately insight hybrid AngularJS/Angular application? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not configured the AngularJS and Angular Router in the correct way, please verify the below steps-

1. Default route (.otherwise) should be removed from AngularJS routing.
2. Implement the 'UrlHandlingStrategy' interface as a part of Angular router config settings to handle the routing for specific URLs. This will avoid the Angular router conflict with AngularJS router-

   export class Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy implements UrlHandlingStrategy {

   shouldProcessUrl(url: UrlTree): boolean {
       return url.toString().startsWith('/ng/');
     }

   extract(url: UrlTree): UrlTree { return url; }
     merge(newUrlPart: UrlTree, rawUrl: UrlTree): UrlTree { return newUrlPart; }
   }
3. Add above class (Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy) as a provider in the root module for URL handling strategy-

   providers: [
       { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: Ng1Ng2UrlHandlingStrategy }
     ]
4. Add both AngularJS and Angular outlet/directive in the app component html

```html
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div class="ng-view"></div>
```

5. Hash based routing will work but setUpLocationSync(upgrade) is required to support the html 5 based routing in the hybrid app. Please update the main.ts file like below-

   upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
   setUpLocationSync(upgrade);

Comment: Ok, please let me know if you need any help.